# SIR model: condition on the equation $R_\infty = 1 - e^{-\lambda k R_\infty}$ to have nonzero solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0107267.pdf) (pages 3 and 4 if you need the context), while I saw this equation on $R_\infty$ (the number of people who finally recovered): $R_\infty = 1 - e^{-\lambda k R_\infty}$.
But, they say

> In order to have a nonzero solution the following condition must be
>   fulfilled: $$ \left. \dfrac{d(1 - e^{-\lambda k R_\infty})}{dR_\infty}
>  \right|_{R_\infty=0} >1 $$

I don't understand why this condition is needed.

Comment: A hint: Just write $\lambda k=:\alpha$ and $R_\infty=:x$. The problem has boiled down to finding conditions on $\alpha>0$ for the equation $$x=1-e^{-\alpha x}$$ to have a solution on $(0,\infty)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Yeah, I found $\alpha >1$ to find a $>0$ solution. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.